# user-group aggregation relationship in UML

Tags: uml, aggregation

if a user can be part of many groups and a group can contain many users , in UML this relationship has to be represented as an Aggregation relationship? or we can just use a simple association ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases an association is sufficient. You would most likely add multiplicity to either end to show that a user (should be) in at least one or can be in many groups (of course this depends on the domain) so you'd see a `1..*` multiplicity. Vice versa a group will have `0..*` users.

You can use `Aggregation` (hollow diamond on the group side) to show that a group is formed by multiple users. Using a composition would usually (in the user management context) not make sense since that means a group can only consist only if there are users which belong to it.

Anyhow, in a user management context I would not use `Aggregation`. The reason is that user and group are both concepts on almost the same level (YMMV) while using `Aggregation` will tell the reader that the aggregated element is on some lower level than the aggregating one.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is clear that "composite" is not an option, so would be either "shared" or "none". OMG specification defines shared like this:

*"Precise semantics of shared aggregation **varies** by application area and modeler. "*

So you can choose from either choices. If you want to represent this in UML diagram,,,,,
[image]

("1..*" might be the right multiplicity..)

My answer is based on UML Specification 2.4.1 - [7.3.2 AggregationKind]

AggregationKind is an enumeration of the following literal values:

**none**

Indicates that the property has no aggregation.

**shared**

Indicates that the property has a shared aggregation.

**composite**

Indicates that the property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (parts).

**Semantic Variation Points**

Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

The order and way in which part instances are created is not defined.